# jmeter http header manager authorization field "bad authentication data"

Tags: jmeter, authorization, twitter-oauth

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQHPR.png)

I passed the twitter oauth 1.0 parameter in authorization field for example:

```
oauth_consumer_key="XXxxXXxxXXXXXxxx",
oauth_nonce="kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg",
oauth_signature="tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_timestamp="1318622958",
oauth_token="ddddddd-xxxXXxxxxXXxxXXXXXxxxxxXXXXxxxxXXxxxxXX", 
oauth_version="1.0"
```

to get the user timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Your format is a little bit wrong, as per [Authorizing a request chapter of Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request.html) you should have `OAuth` statement at the beginning.

So the full request should look something like:

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXxxXXxxXXXXXxxx", oauth_nonce="kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg", oauth_signature="tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1318622958", oauth_token="370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb", oauth_version="1.0"
```

With regards to requests values - it seems you're using hard-coded example values which you should not be using, to wit:

- `oauth_nonce` - you should get it randomly, i.e. using [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function
- `oauth_timestamp` - should be current time, you can get it using i.e. [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function
- `oauth_signature` - must be [calculated](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html), check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for more comprehensive explanation.